# The Endomorphism algebra of graded vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, graded-rings, graded-modules

Let $G$ be a group. A linear map $f:V\rightarrow W$ of $G$-graded vector spaces is said to be *homogeneous of degree $g$* if $f(V_{h}) \subseteq W_{g\cdot h}$
for all $h\in G$. We denote the space all homogeneous maps of degree $g$ by 
$\operatorname{Hom}_g(V,W)$ and we set 
$$
\operatorname{Hom}^{\operatorname{gr}}(V,W) := \bigoplus_{g\in G}\operatorname{Hom}_{g}(V,W)
$$
If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, why does $\operatorname{Hom}^{\operatorname{gr}}(V,W)$  coincide with $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Use a basis of $V$ consisting of homogeneous elements to decompose any linear map as a sum of homogeneous maps.

Comment: Yeah, don’t overthink this, just use arkeet's hint.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that vector spaces of finite dimension are *small.* For details (in a more general setting) see Section 3 in [this article](http://www.csm.ro/reviste/Revue_Mathematique/pdfs/2012/3/Rohrer.pdf).